# how to validate row in datagridview c#

Tags: c#

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        DataGridViewCell Docnamecell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[0].Index];
        DataGridViewCell Gendercell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[1].Index];
        DataGridViewCell Addresscell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index];
        DataGridViewCell Contactnocell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[3].Index];
        DataGridViewCell Datecell = row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[4].Index];
        e.Cancel = !(IsDoc(Docnamecell) && IsGender(Gendercell) && IsAddress(Addresscell) && IsContactno(Contactnocell) && IsDate(Datecell));
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    private Boolean IsDoc(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Docname");
        }
        return false;
    }
    private Boolean IsGender(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Gender");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private Boolean IsAddress(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Address");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private Boolean IsContactno(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Contact no");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private Boolean IsDate(DataGridViewCell cell)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Date");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _validating a row_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: if cell value is empty than it should not go to new row

Comment: please check my code and tell me correction

Comment: You will need to be a lot more specific with what you need and what you have/have tried. As it is, it's really hard to even try analyzing the problem. Please add a descriptive explanation of what you need and why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

why does your validation always reject edit (line `e.Cancel = true;`)?

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DataGridViewCell Docnamecell = row.Cells[0];
    DataGridViewCell Gendercell = row.Cells[1];
    DataGridViewCell Addresscell = row.Cells[2];
    DataGridViewCell Contactnocell = row.Cells[3];
    DataGridViewCell Datecell = row.Cells[4];
    e.Cancel = !(IsDoc(Docnamecell) && IsGender(Gendercell) && IsAddress(Addresscell) && IsContactno(Contactnocell) && IsDate(Datecell));
}
```